# pushing record in between when dropping on Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to use this example as shown [HERE in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UsCFK/60/), the problem i am having is that I would like when dropping to squeeze the new record in between and not swap.  I tried adding a for loop in the drop function that increases the destination record if the target is less than that one or decreases it if the target is more than the destination.

The problem is that I am ending up with repeated positions like 4,4 or 5, 5, 5.  Are there any examples of Kendo UI that i can use with this functionality?, instead of swaping?.

example:

```
id   text      position
1    world        1
2    cup          2
3    Brazil       3
4    2014         4
5    Soccer       5
```

If i move record 4 to the top i would like to

```
id   text      position
4    2014         1
1    World        2
2    Cup          3
3    Brazil       4
5    Soccer       5
```

I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to insert a row when drag/drop is to use the datasource [insert](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-insert) (or [add](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-add)) capability.  At the high level you are inserting the row into the new location, and removing it from the old location.  Kendo's grid will automatically refresh the display - you just need to get the data right.  The next challenge is to get the target row number.  You've done this by adding a column in the grid, and executing target.get("position")).  I've used the datasource.indexOf method for this, and removed the Position column - cleaning up the display.  Ref [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rick_Mortensen/pWcfd/1/). Following is a small excerpt of the code (thanks to Lars below for improvements!)

```
grid.table.kendoDropTargetArea({
    filter: "td",
    group: "gridGroup",
    drop: function (e) {
        e.draggable.hint.hide();
        var target = dataSource.getByUid($(e.draggable.currentTarget).data("uid")),
            destElement = $(e.dropTarget).closest("tr"),
            dest = dataSource.getByUid(destElement.data("uid")),
            destPosition = dataSource.indexOf(dest);

        //not on same item
        if (target.get("id") !== dest.get("id")) {
            dataSource.remove(target);
            dataSource.insert(destPosition, target);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to modify the current fiddle to see this working?. I just want to see where it should be added.

Comment: I'd like to, but I'm using IE 11, and your fiddle doesn't allow me (as a user) to drag/drop at all, and I'm not able to see the problem.

Comment: Oh man.. i did not check this before.., so i guess i cant use this drag and drop because it would not work in IE, sucks

Comment: @ergwin it will work fine with a current version of Kendo UI - see my answer

Comment: Created a jsfiddle from Lars' excellent post, and updated above comments and code.  I've cleaned up the grid display by removing the position column, so that you have 2 examples (Lars and mine) depending on how you want to interface with your users.

Comment: @ergwin if you don't actually have/need a position column, then this solution is better (less code, easier to understand); you could hide the position column in my example too, but the only advantage over this would be that you can sort by the position column (both ways), and that's probably only useful if the position is relevant data for your users

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only trying to modify the order of the rows, your original approach should work. Instead of swapping the position, you need to adjust the position of all other rows depending on their relative position to the source row and target row.

Your drop target definition might then look something like this:

```
grid.table.kendoDropTargetArea({
    filter: "td",
    group: "gridGroup",
    drop: function (e) {
        e.draggable.hint.hide();
        var target = dataSource.getByUid($(e.draggable.currentTarget).data("uid")),
            destElement = $(e.dropTarget).closest("tr"),
            dest = dataSource.getByUid(destElement.data("uid")),
            sourcePosition,
            targetPosition,
            position,
            item;

        //not on same item
        if (target.get("id") !== dest.get("id")) {
            // set new position for dropped item
            sourcePosition = target.get("position");
            targetPosition = dest.get("position");
            if (targetPosition > sourcePosition) {
                targetPosition -= 1;
            }
            target.set("position", targetPosition);

            // update positions for all other items
            for (var i = 0, max = dataSource.total(); i < max; i++) {
                item = dataSource.at(i);
                if (item.uid === target.uid) continue;
                position = item.position;

                // items which had a higher position than the source item need to move down by one
                if (position >= sourcePosition) {
                    position -= 1;
                }
                // items which had a higher position than the target position need to move up by one
                if (position >= targetPosition) {
                    position += 1;
                }

                item.set("position", position);
            }

            dataSource.sort({
                field: "position",
                dir: "asc"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/uWUW3/))

Comment: Is there a way to minimize the weight on the for loop, with 2500 items it becomes a little too much for it.

Comment: depends on what you need - the for loop itself isn't that expensive, but updating the DOM elements is; so when you enable paging + virtual scrolling, it works for 2500 without problems: http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/uWUW3/11/